# Slow loading images with jQuery plugins

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jqplot

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 website which uses a couple jQuery plugins ([jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) and [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/)).  I've noticed from time to time, especially as I'm developing new pages with new CSS, that the images are slow to load; sometimes taking more than a minute to appear.

On jqGrid, I primarily notice this with the paging icons which come from the jQuery UI sprite (`images/ui-icons_6da8d5_256x240.png`).

On jqPlot, I notice this on custom point labels that use a CSS class with a image background (`url(/Content/images/gray_block.png)`).

In both cases the paths to the images are valid, but for some reason they are very slow to appear.  Has anyone else experienced a similar issue?

Comment: Yup, and my solution is i use full `CSS3` code for design and for background i crop image 1x1px

Comment: Can you expand a bit on your solution?  I don't completely follow.  Unfortunately, I have to support IE8.  So CSS3 may not be an option.

Comment: I doubt that these images are the cause of your problem. The problem could be due to a multitude of possibilities from slow response time, blocking code to something as simple as a 404. Is this website public? If so, post the link please.

Comment: Sorry, it's not on a public website.  Of your suggestions: I know it's not 404, the paths to the images are good. Slow response time seems unlikely, since the rest of the page loads fine.  Blocking code would be the most likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preloading the images fixed the issue. I used the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.preload = function () {
        this.each(function () {
            $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        });
    }
</script>

// pre-cache icons
$(['@Url.Content("~/Content/images/orange_block.png")', 
   '@Url.Content("~/Content/images/yellow_block.png")', 
   '@Url.Content("~/Content/images/red_block.png")',
   '@Url.Content("~/Content/images/gray_block.png")',
   '@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/custom-theme/images/ui-icons_217bc0_256x240.png")'
 ]).preload();
```